# Use knockout-kendo binding with MultiSelectBox plugin

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I try to use MultiSelectBox KendoUI plugin shown in following fiddle with knockout binding, but I can't make it work

[KendoUI plugin for drop-down with checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/bDvkQ/)

My multiselect is defined as below

```
<input 
    data-role="multiselectbox"
    data-bind= "kendoMultiSelectBox: {
                            dataTextField: 'Desc',
                            dataValueField: 'ID',
                            data: ProjectTypes,
                            value: pID
                        },
                        event: { change: changeProjectType }" />
```

Any suggestion on how to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Could you please post the code of your kendoMultiSelectBox bindingHandler? 2) In what way is your current solution not working? 3) What error do you get? 4) If possible, could you please create a jsfiddle/plnkr/jsbin which shows your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work as follows:

```
<input data-bind= "kendoMultiSelect: {
                        dataTextField: 'Desc',
                        dataValueField: 'ID',
                        data: ProjectTypes,
                        value: pID
                   },
                   event: { 
                        change: changeProjectType 
                   }" />
```

The key element was **kendoMultiSelect** binding